# Qt and Sqlite examples

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am looking for some example code using Qt and it's SQL module with Sqlite driver. Main reason I need examples for is that I've prior experience with Qt's database interface and Sqlite has some weird behavior with field types (types are stored per-field, not per-column).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [Qt 5 SQL examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-sql.html) use SQLite as this does not require a database server. You should be able to go from the supplied examples to your own sample code pretty quickly.