# Unable to open sqlite database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a simple app that I am doing that will load a list for my inventory.  I am doing this to learn a little bit about Qt because it looks really neat.

I have a few windows and a database that all those windows pull data from.  I get 8 compile errors when following the built in examples (though they all are for in memory databases)

the errors are

```
  undefined reference to `_imp__ZN12QSqlDatabase17defaultConnectionE'
  undefined reference to `_imp__ZN12QSqlDatabase11addDatabaseERK7QStringS2_'
  undefined reference to `_imp__ZN12QSqlDatabaseD1Ev'
  undefined reference to `_imp__ZN12QSqlDatabase15setDatbaseNameERK7QString'
  undefined reference to `_imp__ZN12QSqlDatabase4openEv'
  undefined reference to `_imp__ZN12QSqlDatabaseD1Ev'
  undefined reference to `_imp__ZN12QSqlDatabaseD1Ev'

  collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

here is my connection header

***connection.h***

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_H
#define CONNECTION_H

#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

static bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("C:\\Inventory.db");
    if (db.open()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

#endif // CONNECTION_H
```

the only thing I have done with connection.h is import it into mainwindow.cpp

I haven't found any real world examples (not examples, tutorials I mean) of sqlite usage (I don't see how an in memory sqlite database is helpful for a lot of people [though I am highly novice])

Thank you for any help SO

These are imported into mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlTableModel>

#include "connection.h"
```

Comment: Are you sure you've added all the right import libraries to your project?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not finding real-world examples of SQLite usage - as they say on their home page, it's the [most widely deployed SQL database engine](http://www.sqlite.org/mostdeployed.html). Sure, they're probably more commonly on-sidk than in-memory, but they're still bona fide usage.

Comment: @Jefomi:  Sorry, I meant tutorial examples

Comment: Perhaps this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429782/qt-and-sqlite-examples

Comment: @Jefomi:  Those are using the in memory database.  I was under the impression my problem was from Qt not being able to find my database.  An in-memory database won't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following file to your *.pro file:

```
QT += sql
```

and do a qmake and build.