# Qt -C++ Searchable DataTable to DataGrid Functionality?

Tags: c++, qt

In C# .net you can build in memory datatables and run sql like queries with LINQ on it, then display the results in a Datagrid in your application.

What would be the equivalent tools to use in QT C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429782/qt-and-sqlite-examples).

It doesn't provide LINQ-like syntax, but it allows you to keep your DB in memory.
And you can bind your presenters (e.g. Datagrid) to the data provided from that DB via table/query.